# SQL LIKE без учёта NULL ячеек

Tags: mysql, php, sql

День добрый!

У меня по закону фрейморка все пустые ячейки в БД MySQL, должны быть NULL, но у меня есть SQL запрос, который подразумевает поиск пользователей по 4 критериям, имя, фамилия, город, пол. Но возникает проблема, если у пользователя хотя бы одна из этих ячеек NULL, то она не попадает под LIKE и соответственно под результат, как мне это утрясти?

```
$users = Users::findByRawSql('u.f_name LIKE ? AND u.s_name LIKE ? AND u.sex LIKE ? AND u.city LIKE ?', array(
            $this->_addLike($this->request->getPost('f_name')),
            $this->_addLike($this->request->getPost('s_name')),
            $this->_addLike($this->request->getPost('sex')),
            $this->_addLike($this->request->getPost('city'))
        ));

$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.avatar, u.city, u.f_name, u.s_name, u.notes, u.username, SUM(b.summ) AS summ
FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN balance AS b ON b.user_id = u.id
WHERE $conditions GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY summ DESC";
```

Comment: Запрос в студию!

Comment: Думаю, не надо генерить запросы типа `.... field LIKE '%%'`

Comment: @eicto, не волнуйтесь, у меня фреймворком включены методы предостороженности.

@Donil, Сори забыл)) Добавил в шапку.

Comment: Именем закона фреймворка!

*извините*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо имени столбца используйте [COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html), например:

COALESCE(u.f_name, '') LIKE

Comment: Странно, в редакторе запросов PhpStorm при выполнении работает, а в коде системы почему-то нет.

Comment: @chuikoff, скорее всего экранирование запроса где-то по пути превращает функцию в строку.

Comment: @Etki, видимо, да, можно как-то это обойти?

Comment: @chuikoff, без знания хотя бы названия фреймворка и вида обновленного запроса сказать ничего нельзя.

Comment: Вероятно, нужно экранировать одинарные кавычки, типа

COALESCE(u.f_name, \'\') LIKE...

Или весь запрос оформить в двойных.